# How to open Android's contact book or dialer from a tab widget?

Tags: android, android-tabs

Is it possible to open Android's default Contact Book or Dialer from a tab widget?

Relevant code (currently not working):

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Dialler",
                  null)
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```